# Filter Command Not Working in a Reactive in Shiny

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I am attempting to create a data frame by filtering a variable from a different data set.  The following code works properly:

```
devtools::install_github("meysubb/cfbscrapR")
library(cfbscrapR)
library(tidyverse)

pretend <- mutate(
    cfb_game_info(2015) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE")
  )
```

However, when I wrap it into a reactive in Shiny, I get the following error messages:

Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Here is my code in the reactive (note the packages in the previous block of working code):

```
games <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      req(input$year, input$conferencegame)
      if(input$year=="2015" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2015) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE"))
      } else if(input$year=="2015" & input$conferencegame=="ALL"){ 
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2015) %>% rename("game_id" = id))
      } else if(input$year=="2016" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2016) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE"))
      } else if(input$year=="2016" & input$conferencegame=="ALL"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2016) %>% rename("game_id" = id))
      } else if(input$year=="2017" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2017) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE"))
      } else if(input$year=="2017" & input$conferencegame=="ALL"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2017) %>% rename("game_id" = id))
      } else if(input$year=="2018" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2018) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE"))
      } else if(input$year=="2018" & input$conferencegame=="ALL"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2018) %>% rename("game_id" = id))
      } else if(input$year=="2019" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
                  mutate(cfb_game_info(2019) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE"))
      } else {mutate(cfb_game_info(2019) %>% rename("game_id" = id))
      }
    })
  })
```

Also, in case it helps, here is the ui.R section that uses the aforementioned inputs:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("conferencegame", label = h4(
      "Choose All or Only Conference Games"),
      choices = list("All" = "ALL", "Conference" = "CONF")
    ),
    actionButton("submit", "Update"),
    width = 4),
mainPanel(
    selectInput("year", "Choose Year, then Click Update",
                c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"),
                selected = "2019"),
  )
)
```

As requested, a reproducible example:

```
devtools::install_github("meysubb/cfbscrapR")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/gt")

#Install and run the Rcpp package if not done

library(tidyverse)
library(cfbscrapR)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(rsconnect)
library(logger)
library(shinyjs)

######################
#Data
######################
pbp_2019 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:15){
  data <- cfb_pbp_data(year = 2019, week = i, epa_wpa = TRUE) %>% mutate(week = i)
  df <- data.frame(data)
  pbp_2019 <- bind_rows(pbp_2019, df) %>% mutate(garbage = ifelse(period == 1 & abs(score_diff) > 43, 1, 
                                                                  ifelse(period == 2 & abs(score_diff) > 37, 1,
                                                                         ifelse(period == 3 & abs(score_diff) > 27, 1,
                                                                                ifelse(period == 4 & abs(score_diff) > 22, 1, 0)))))
}

drives_2019 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:15){
  data <- cfb_pbp_data(year = 2019, week = i, drive = TRUE) %>% mutate(week = i)
  df <- data.frame(data)
  drives_2019 <- bind_rows(drives_2019, df)
}

pbp_2018 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:15){
  data <- cfb_pbp_data(year = 2018, week = i, epa_wpa = TRUE) %>% mutate(week = i)
  df <- data.frame(data)
  pbp_2018 <- bind_rows(pbp_2018, df) %>% mutate(garbage = ifelse(period == 1 & abs(score_diff) > 43, 1, 
                                                                  ifelse(period == 2 & abs(score_diff) > 37, 1,
                                                                         ifelse(period == 3 & abs(score_diff) > 27, 1,
                                                                                ifelse(period == 4 & abs(score_diff) > 22, 1, 0)))))
}

drives_2018 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:15){
  data <- cfb_pbp_data(year = 2018, week = i, epa_wpa = TRUE, drive = TRUE ) %>% mutate(week = i)
  df <- data.frame(data)
  drives_2018 <- bind_rows(drives_2018, df)
}

pbp_2017 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:15){
  data <- cfb_pbp_data(year = 2017, week = i, epa_wpa = TRUE) %>% mutate(week = i)
  df <- data.frame(data)
  pbp_2017 <- bind_rows(pbp_2017, df) %>% mutate(garbage = ifelse(period == 1 & abs(score_diff) > 43, 1, 
                                                                  ifelse(period == 2 & abs(score_diff) > 37, 1,
                                                                         ifelse(period == 3 & abs(score_diff) > 27, 1,
                                                                                ifelse(period == 4 & abs(score_diff) > 22, 1, 0)))))
}

drives_2017 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:15){
  data <- cfb_pbp_data(year = 2017, week = i, epa_wpa = TRUE, drive = TRUE ) %>% mutate(week = i)
  df <- data.frame(data)
  drives_2017 <- bind_rows(drives_2017, df)
}

#######
#UI
#######
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1("College Football Analytics")),
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("conferencegame", label = h4(
      "Choose All or Only Conference Games"),
      choices = list("All" = "ALL", "Conference" = "CONF")
    ),
    radioButtons("garbagetime", label = h4(
      "Choose to Filter Garbage Time"),
      choices = list("All" = 1,
                     "Remove Garbage Time" = 0),
    ),
    actionButton("submit", "Update"),
    width = 4),
  mainPanel(
    selectInput("year", "Choose Year, then Click Update",
                c("2017", "2018", "2019"),
                selected = "2019")
    ),
  DTOutput(outputId = "example")
  )

########
#Server
########

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cfb.table2 <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      if(input$year=="2017"){
        pbp_2017
      } else if(input$year=="2018"){
        pbp_2018
      } else {
        pbp_2019
      }
    })})
  
  game_numbers <- reactive({cfb.table2() %>% group_by(offense_play, game_id) %>% mutate(num=1) %>% summarise(game.n = mean(num)) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(offense_play) %>% mutate(game.number = cumsum(game.n)) %>% select(-game.n)})
  
  plays <- reactive({cfb.table2() %>% filter(rush == 1 | pass == 1) %>% left_join(game_numbers(), by=c("game_id","offense_play"))})
  
  offense <- reactive({plays() %>% group_by(offense_play) %>% summarise(ypa = mean(yards_gained[pass==1]), ypr = mean(yards_gained[rush==1]), num.plays = n()) %>% filter(num.plays > 300)})
  offense <- reactive({plays() %>% group_by(offense_play) %>% summarise(epa.pass.off = mean(EPA[pass==1]), success.rate = mean(success), epa.rush.off = mean(EPA[rush==1]), num.plays = n()) %>% filter(num.plays > 300)})
  defense <- reactive({plays() %>% group_by(defense_play) %>% summarise(epa.pass.def = mean(EPA[pass==1]), epa.rush.def = mean(EPA[rush==1]), num.plays = n()) %>% filter(num.plays > 300)})
  update.epa <- reactive({left_join(offense(), defense(), by = c("offense_play" = "defense_play"))})
  plays.garbage <- reactive({plays() %>% mutate(drive_id=as.character(drive_id)) %>% group_by(game_id, drive_id) %>% summarise(garbage = max(garbage))})
  
  drives.table2 <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      if(input$year=="2017"){
        drives_2017
      } else if(input$year=="2018"){
        drives_2018
      } else{
        drives_2019
      }
    })
  })  
  
  games <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      if(input$year=="2017" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
        cfb_game_info(2017) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE")
      } else if(input$year=="2017" & input$conferencegame=="ALL"){
        cfb_game_info(2017) %>% rename("game_id" = id)
      } else if(input$year=="2018" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
        cfb_game_info(2018) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE")
      } else if(input$year=="2018" & input$conferencegame=="ALL"){
        cfb_game_info(2018) %>% rename("game_id" = id)
      } else if(input$year=="2019" & input$conferencegame=="CONF"){
        cfb_game_info(2019) %>% rename("game_id" = id) %>% filter(conference_game=="TRUE")
      } else {cfb_game_info(2019) %>% rename("game_id" = id)
      }
    })
  })
  
  drives.off.tmp <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      if (input$garbagetime==0) {
        drives.table2() %>% left_join(games(), by = c("game_id")) %>% 
          left_join(plays.garbage(), by = c("game_id", "id"="drive_id")) %>% filter(garbage==0)
      } else {
        drives.table2() %>% left_join(games(), by = c("game_id"))
      }
    })
  })
  
  drives.off <- reactive({drives.off.tmp() %>%
      mutate(
        adj_start_yardline = ifelse(offense == away_team, 100-start_yardline, start_yardline), 
        success = ifelse(drive_result %in% c("TD", "FG"), 1, 0),
        drive.pts = ifelse(drive_result == "TD", 6, ifelse(drive_result == "FG", 3, 0))) %>%
      group_by(offense, offense_conference) %>% 
      summarise(
        fp = mean(adj_start_yardline[adj_start_yardline > 10 & adj_start_yardline <40]), 
        srate = mean(success),
        drives = n(),
        drives.pts = sum(drive.pts))
  })
  
  output$example <- renderDT({
    drives.off()
  })
}
  
#Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, so please include some example data and a short running app

Comment: My apologies, just added the packages needed for the dataset

Comment: Thanks, and please also add a complete server function, not only your games function

Comment: Those errors I would expect to come from code trying to draw a plot, but there's no plotting code here. Is there something you've left out?

Comment: Just added entire server.R

Comment: Thanks! Please note that the *complete* server is not a minimal reproducible example either. Try to leave out as much as possible, only include what you need to reproduce your problem. When leaving stuff out, you might discover the possible error source

Comment: Now more data and other UI elements are missing. I'm not able to help you if you don't provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @starja added how to produce the data, UI and server while taking out the repetitive lines of code

Comment: The input `games.subset` is missing. Your code is still very long and complex, try to make it even easier

Comment: @starja Ok, gave it another try for a reproducible example.  I read your suggestions for making examples more reproducible and this is my best shot.

Comment: Your example works for me

Answer (score 0):

Below you find a working example. The problem here was that your data.frame contains 2 list columns (`away_line_scores` and `home_line_scores`). Apparently, `renderTable` cannot deal with list columns. Therefore I used `DT` which coerces the list. Alternatively, you could leave out the two columns (see the comment).

However, your code has some more issues

- you don't need to wrap `mutate` around your other commands when creating a new data.frame
- you can use the `input$` variables directly in `dplyr`, no need for `if/else`
- if you want to update an expression based on a button, you should use `eventReactive`

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(cfbscrapR)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("conferencegame", label = h4(
      "Choose All or Only Conference Games"),
      choices = list("All" = "ALL", "Conference" = "CONF")
    ),
    actionButton("submit", "Update"),
    width = 4),
  mainPanel(
    selectInput("year", "Choose Year, then Click Update",
                c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019),
                selected = 2019),
    DTOutput(outputId = "example")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  games <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    
    pretend <- cfb_game_info(as.numeric(input$year)) %>%
                        rename("game_id" = id)
    if (input$conferencegame == "CONF") {
      pretend <- pretend %>% 
        filter(conference_game == TRUE)
    }
    
    pretend
                      
  })
  
  output$example <- renderDT({
    games() # %>% select(-c(away_line_scores, home_line_scores))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**

The shown solution is for a previously provided code/data example without the complete server function.

Comment: Some helpful tips here, but ultimately the frame I'm putting into a data table takes out those list items.  Hopefully the reproducible example I recently posted shows what I mean.